# What is the audible range on a soda?

Tags: dayz-2012

When you drink a soda, it makes a snap and gulp sound which can alert nearby zombies.  Up to how far can this sound be heard by them?

Comment: I would have an answer for this, but my teammate (who had a few cans of soda) didn't want to waste his soda. Never mind the fact that he had three full canteens.

Comment: @Fluttershy - I can understand that.  It *is* a waste of resources.

Comment: This is the greatest question title.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what the actual distance is, but I have heard another player drink from at least 20m before.

Edit: Also each gun has an audible distance for zombies, but players can hear the gunshots MUCH further than the listed distances that will aggro zombies.  I would not be surprised if you can hear another player eat/drink from further than zombies can hear it.